# Ajuda basename + url [PHP]

Tags: php

Tenho esse código:

```
if(count($vid_files)>0){
    $videoNames = array_keys($vid_files);
    $videoName = basename($videoNames[0]);
    $this->videourl = $videoName;
```

Eu gostaria de adicionar uma url no inicio depois do resultado da **basename**, o resultando dela é **100392video.mp4** eu queria que a url ficasse na frente, exemplo.

```
$this->videourl = "url" + $videoName;
```

Só que quando faço isso, sai apena os números.

```
100392
```

E não sai nenhuma url nem o final que é **.mp4**.

Em responda ao Isac;

```
    public function add($f3, $id, $name, $userid, $category, $vid_files){
        //add or edit to db
    if($id>=0){
        $this->load(array('id = ?',$id));
    }
    $this->userid = $userid;
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->category = $category;

    if(count($vid_files)>0){
        $videoNames = array_keys($vid_files);
        $videoName = basename($videoNames[0]);
        $this->videourl = $videoName;
    }

    $this->save();
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($vid_files);` antes do `if` apresenta o que?

Comment: A minha questão foi no sentido de perceber o que tem exatamente a sua variavel `$vid_files` que apenas pela pergunta não dá para perceber. Ainda assim na resposta(que deveria ser uma edição da pergunta) não me parece que tenha colocado no sitio correto. A ideia é colocar exatamente antes da utilização, que seria antes de `if(count($vid_files)>0){` e mostrar-nos o que sai como resultado desse var_dump

Comment: @Isac seria isso?

Comment: Nem por isso, pois ainda não é claro o que `$vid_files` tem. Coloque `var_dump($vid_files);` na linha exatamente antes de `if(count($vid_files)>0){`. Depois volte a testar e coloque na pergunta o resultado que o `var_dump` deu.

Comment: @Isac eu não consigo ver o que tem no vid_files.

Comment: @Isac tem alguma ideia?

Comment: `basename` vai buscar a parte final do caminho, que será o nome do arquivo. No entanto se não consegue saber o que está a ir buscar em `$vid_files[0]` torna-se impossível de ajudar. Só mesmo tentando adivinhar. Fazendo uma pequena analogia, é como tentar pedir a um mecânico que arranje o seu carro sem abrir o capot, só pelo som que faz. Só vai ficar com o carro arranjado se tiver a sorte de ele conseguir adivinhar o problema pelo som.

Comment: @Isac da para juntar "URL" + $videoNames[0] ?

Comment: Dá, mas concatenar em php é com `.` e não `+`, assumindo que estamos a falar de strings

Comment: @Isac nossa, desculpa! era isso mesmo, esqueci que para concatenar com php era com `.` kkkk, obg Isac :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema ocorre pois você está "somando" e não "concatenando".

troque isso:

```
$this->videourl = "url" + $videoName;
```

por isso:

```
$this->videourl = "url" . $videoName;
```

o código antigo soma numeros, no caso url vale `0` e video name `100392`, por isso o resultado.

Como diz na documentação do [PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.string.php)

**Operadores de String**

Há dois operadores de string. O primeiro é o operador de concatenação `('.')`, que retorna a concatenação dos seus argumentos direito e esquerdo. O segundo é o operador de atribuição de concatenação `('.=')`, que acrescenta o argumento do lado direito no argumento do lado esquerdo. Veja em Operadores de Atribuição para mais informações.

```
<?php
$a = "Olá ";
$b = $a . "mundo!"; // agora $b contém "Olá mundo!"

$a = "Olá ";
$a .= "mundo!"; // agora $a contém "Olá mundo!"
?>
```

Para números sim, utilizamos o +

```
echo 1+2; //mostra o numero 3
```

**Mas calma**

Pois é normal acontecer esses erros, principalmente pra quem desenvolve em linguagens como o java que a concatenação de string é feita com o `+` também.